# vsftp: why is allow_writeable_chroot=YES a bad idea?

Tags: security, chroot, vsftpd

There are several thousand blog posts about vsftp and `allow_writeable_chroot=YES`

The common error message:

> Fixing 500 OOPS: vsftpd: refusing to run with writable root inside chroot ()

I solved the problem on my server.

But one question remains:

Why is it advisable to use `allow_writeable_chroot=NO`?

Up to now I only found nebulous arguments like "For security reasons".

What are these "security reasons"?

Comment: Where is the official documentation for `allow_writeable_chroot`?

Comment: Nowhere : https://security.appspot.com/vsftpd.html but you may have an answer there : #vsftpd IRC channel at irc.freenode.net.

Answer (score 11):

If the FTP credentials of a user (even a virtual user) with a writeable `chroot` get compromised, the attacker might conceivably be able to perform a [ROARING BEAST ATTACK](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/332571/29001). To summarise my rough understanding of this attack, it involves exploiting the fact that some C libraries (perhaps including ones used by the FTP server) will look for dynamic libraries that they depend on at hard-coded paths in `/etc` or other common locations. The attacker uploads evil versions of those dynamic libraries to the `/etc` *within the `chroot`*, then sends a command to the (running-as-root) FTP server that induces it to run some code that loads in that dynamic library from `/etc`. The attacker's evil code then runs as root. This escalates the attack from a mere compromise of the user's FTP folder to rooting the entire machine.

Having a non-writeable chroot renders this attack impossible (unless you, the sysadmin, have unwisely created writeable folders with names like `/etc` and `/lib` within your FTP users' `chroot` directories).

Comment: I like to switch the perspective and to look at the world through the eyes of a evil black hat hacker :-) Thank you for the link to the roaring beast attack. Lazy loading of libraries ... then loading from chroot ... nice.

Comment: Why would vsfrpd load _any_ libraries, evil or not from /etc within a chroot???

Comment: @AndrewSavinykh because once you've `chroot`ed the `/etc` within the `chroot` just looks like `/etc` - that's the whole point of `chroot`ing - and the standard mechanism for loading dynamic libraries looks for stuff in `/etc` and `/lib`. Or at least, that's my understanding of the linked post and of https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/22999/29001!

Answer (score 2):

The main concern is that it makes dotfiles writable. Depending on your shell, the way login is set up, whether $HOME/.ssh is used, what other services are running and a few other things, this provides a lot more attack surface to abuse, mostly through manipulation of user environment variables. There isn't a comprehensive guide on what and why because that would require knowing the attacks before they happen.

Long story short, for usability, most distributions reference a user's home directory in one way or another and making it writable means those references could potentially be manipulated.

Comment: .ssh/authorized_keys is not (directly) inside $HOME. A readonly $HOME does not help for this file. And for `.bashrc`: if you are allowed to login into this $HOME, then you can set any environment variable you like interactively. I still don't get it.