# How to allow a vsftpd to write to a folder other than default `/files`?

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, ftp, vsftpd

I'm new to FTP and I've been following [this DigitalOcean tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-vsftpd-for-a-user-s-directory-on-ubuntu-16-04).

Everything works great except that a user (at least in FileZilla) cannot write to the root of his `/home/user/ftp` folder, only `/home/user/ftp/files`. An attempt to create in the root folder results in:

> Command:  PASV 
>   Response: 227 Entering Passive Mode (104,131,29,61,191,224).
>
> Command:  STOR asdfa
>
> Response: **553 Could not create file**.
>
> Error: Critical file transfer error

I scanned `/etc/vsftpd.conf` file for the word `files` but I can't find that config anywhere. I've used FTP before and generally you drop and and the files are right there, without needing to navigate to folders.

Is this a `chown` problem of some sort in Ubuntu?

#### Is it possible to just allow a user to write to root and if so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your default `/etc/vsftpd.conf` doesn't initially include all the possible directives the configuration file supports. The rest can be found from `man vsftpd.conf`.

Answer to your question can be found in the very [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-vsftpd-for-a-user-s-directory-on-ubuntu-16-04) you are following:

> FTP is generally more secure when users are restricted to a specific
>   directory. vsftpd accomplishes this with chroot jails. When chroot is
>   enabled for local users, they are restricted to their home directory
>   by default. However, because of the way vsftpd secures the directory,
>   it must not be writable by the user. This is fine for a new user who
>   should only connect via FTP, but an existing user may need to write to
>   their home folder if they also shell access.

In other words, you have created the `/home/user/ftp` folder to allow vsftp use chroot jails without making the home folder `/home/user/` read only to the user. Therefore you are already doing best practices and should not be worried about the error as it is normal and desired behaviour.

It is *possible* but highly not recommended to disable chroot jail.

If this is only about enchanging the user experience, you could try append directly to `/home/user/ftp/files` after login by adding/modifying vsftp.conf directives:

```
user_sub_token=$USER
local_root=/home/$USER/ftp/files
```

Comment: Will software which relies on access to said FTP will follow your last suggestion? Last I heard it's *configured* to look in root, hence the problem.

Comment: Supposedly the the FTP client appends now directly to `/home/$USER/ftp/files` which should been seen as FTP root now, but haven't personally tested (as I'm not running vsftpd on a test environment). Please reply or accept the answer, if the last suggestion actually does the magic. :)

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to make the `/home/user/ftp` directory writable again (it was disabled in the tutorial)

```
sudo chmod a+w /home/sammy/ftp
```

and enable writable chroot in vsftp config:

```
allow_writeable_chroot=YES
```

However, this option is considered **DANGEROUS**. It's prone to the "Roaring Beast" attack. You can find more info about the risk here:

- [vsftp: why is allow_writeable_chroot=YES a bad idea?](https://serverfault.com/questions/743949/vsftp-why-is-allow-writeable-chroot-yes-a-bad-idea)
- [What are the dangers of having writable chroot directory for FTP?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/323711/what-are-the-dangers-of-having-writable-chroot-directory-for-ftp/332571)