# Cant restrict FTP access to www directory - CentOS7

Tags: centos, ftp, vsftpd

### Objective:

I am trying to create a simple sftp access to the `/var/www/` directory.

### My Problem:

When I login via ftp, although I get access to the `/var/www/` -I have access to the root directory also.
I changed the *chroot* option as mentioned below to *YES* but still the problem persists. I cant seem to restrict access just to the `/var/www` folder.

Any help is appreciated.

### Environment

- CentOS7

### Config

Below is my `/etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf` file

I created the user like so;

```
sudo useradd -m ftpuser -d /var/www/
sudo passwd ftpuser
```

With the config file below, I have tried both with

```
chroot_local_user=YES
```

and

```
chroot_local_user=NO
```

### VSFTPD Conf file

```
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
local_umask=022
allow_ftpd_full_access
dirmessage_enable=YES                                                 
xferlog_enable=YES              
xferlog_std_format=YES                  
connect_from_port_20=YES                                                                
userlist_enable=YES     

chroot_local_user=YES

listen=NO                                    
listen_ipv6=YES                                                                                     
pam_service_name=vsftpd
tcp_wrappers=YES

ssl_enable=YES
rsa_cert_file=/etc/path_to_my_cert.pem
rsa_private_key_file=/etc/path_to_my_keyv.pem
```

Comment: Did you restart VSFTP after making your changes?

Comment: yes, I used `sudo systemctl restart vsftpd`

Answer (score 0):

If you can show all directories then try by following:-

```
allow_writable_chroot=YES
```

then restart ftp service

Comment: Is this not a bad idea based on this thread: https://serverfault.com/questions/743949/vsftp-why-is-allow-writeable-chroot-yes-a-bad-idea

Comment: ensure that you would allow particular directory access to particular user (not a root user)

Comment: so chmod 755 on the /var/www/USER/